Lines not plotting after a weekend or a holiday
I am trying to plot two lines in the future after the day has ended on the INTRADAY CHART.
Here is the code I tried
//@version=5
indicator("My script", "test", true)//, max_lines_count = 6)

previousClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", close[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])
previousOpen  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",  open[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])

var openTime  = 0

if session.islastbar_regular // Using the last bar as i want to plot it in the future
    openTime := time
    closeTime = openTime + 1440*60*1000
    line.new(openTime, previousClose, closeTime, previousClose, xloc.bar_time, extend.none, color.red)
    line.new(openTime, previousOpen, closeTime, previousOpen, xloc.bar_time, extend.none, color.green)

In this code, the lines are not plotting properly after weekend or holiday
I also want to display only the latest day lines

The lines are not plotted corretly after a weekend or a holiday because the end point of your lines is 1 day (in milliseconds) away from the bar where the lines start, but the actual bar opens more than a day away.
You can fix it by replacing the closeTime variable with this calculation:
closeTime = time_close("1D", -1)

The time_close() function calculates the closing time of the next daily candle (-1, relative to the current candle which is 0).

Thank you so much. It solved the issue.
Love this community that helps each other learn and grow
